# Google Api Authentication Failed

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-api, desktop-application

I am implementing sentiment analysis in dot net using google cloud API.
and my code is

```
string text = "Feeling Not Well";
var client = LanguageServiceClient.Create();

var response = client.AnalyzeSentiment(Document.FromPlainText(text));
var sentiment = response.DocumentSentiment;
var Score = sentiment.Score;
var magnitude = sentiment.Magnitude;
```

when i execute 
LanguageServiceClient.Create();
 it gives run time exception of google Authentication failed..
please give me the solution of google ApI authentication.

Comment: [https://myaccount.google.com/security?nlr=1&pli=1](https://myaccount.google.com/security?nlr=1&pli=1) at the bottom of site there is allow low secured applications, enable it. i think it helps you

Comment: Ikram I want to Authenticate through coding.enable API by manually on every machine is not a good aproach.

Comment: Before using the client library you first have to authenticate. Run this command `gcloud beta auth application-default login`. Please see more [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries). Also the guide here https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#getting_credentials_for_server-centric_flow

Comment: Zaggler, as i already said Authentication through command is not a good aproach.it will have to run of every machine,so i think its bad approach.i want some other good techinique.

Comment: @John ***Did you read the guide***, my guess is you did not. In the guide it explains this, you would have to use OAuth in order to authenticate to use the API. Please ***read the guide*** before making assumptions as well as not trying anything. If you disagree and you think there is another approach, how about you contact Google and ask them about another technique... This is the way it is done.